# Sweetalert not waiting for user action and proceeds with code flow

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sweetalert

```
swal({title: "Sure ?", text: "Your form will be submitted", confirmButtonText: "Ok",  
showConfirmButton:true, showCancelButton: true, cancelButtonText: "No", type:"warning", closeOnConfirm: false,
                    closeOnCancel: false },
                     function(isConfirm) {
                                if (isConfirm) {
                                    swal({
                                        title: 'Confirm!',
                                        text: 'Successfully Submitted!',
                                        type: 'success'
                                    }, function() {
                                        console.log("Inside Function"); 
                                        $scope.applyleave("ok");


                                    });

                            } else {
swal("Cancelled", "Your application not submitted :)", "error");
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
```

code flow should be continued only on clicking Ok but it executes without any user execution

I am submitting the form from html to this JS but i want the block the confirm box and wait for user action and allow the below code to execute only when user press Ok

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is the nature of javascript event handling.

To achieve the effect of normal popup, wrap things that needs to be run only when user responded in a function, and then call it in the `isConfirm` function.

Normal popup:

```
if (confirm("ORLY?")) {
    console.log("YO!");
}
else {
    console.log("AWW!");
}

console.log("KTHXBAI!");
```

swal:

```
swal({ title: "ORLY?" },
    function(isConfirm) {
        if (confirm("ORLY?")) {
            console.log("YO!");
        }
        else {
            console.log("AWW!");
        }

        finally();
        // you can also write codes directly here
    });

function finally() {
    console.log("KTHXBAI!");
}
```